# Modifying settings.xml proxy settings for Maven

Tags: maven, proxy, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a Maven project on Google Compute Engine.

When I run it it gets an error that Maven can't connect to the internet (can't retrieve plugin etc).

As I'm new to Compute Engine, I do not know how to configure the VM Instance to let Maven access to the internet.

My wild guess is that VM Instances use proxies and I have to configure the bellow configuration in the settings.xml.

I would like to know how to get all these proxy informations.

```
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy                                                                                                  
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.                                    
     |                                                                                                          
    <proxy>                                                                                                     
      <id>optional</id>                                                                                         
      <active>true</active>                                                                                     
      <protocol>http</protocol>                                                                                 
      <username>proxyuser</username>                                                                            
      <password>proxypass</password>                                                                            
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>                                                                               
      <port>80</port>                                                                                           
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>                                                    
    </proxy>                                                                                                    
    -->
  </proxies>
```

Also, maybe do I have to configure the firewall?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking

Comment: @rkosegi I allowed http and https connection to my firewall and it still has issues to connect to org.apache.maven.org/* to retrieve plugins. Do you know if there's something else I need to allow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just built my Maven project offline and sent the jar file into the VM.